# Javascript per field function on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked for some help on how to best solve this problem. I have 3 different prices and when a user clicks "yes" in the drop down, I would like to go to a hidden field. Please see below as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/adder1999/BsMkj/

```
 <div>
                   <label>Three</label>
                     <input type="text" name="oneprice"  value="20.50"  />
                     <select name="oneswitch"  onChange="calculate()" />
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                      </select>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                   <label>Two</label>
                     <input type="text" name="twoprice"  value="23.50"  />
                     <select name="twoswitch"  onChange="calculate()" />
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                      </select>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                   <label>Three</label>
                     <input type="text" name="threeprice"  value="13.50"  />
                     <select name="threeswitch"  onChange="calculate()" />
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                      </select>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                     <input type="hidden" name="total_oneprice"  value="0.00"  />
                     <input type="hidden" name="total_twoprice"  value="0.00"  />
                     <input type="hidden" name="total_threeprice"  value="0.00"  />
                 </div>
```

Here is the javascript, but I don't know how to make it work based on each field. How do I change this to read if yes on oneprice, then add to total_oneprice?  If yes on twoprice, then add to total_twoprice?  If yes on threeprice then add to total_threeprice?

```
 <script>
$('select').on('change',function() {
    $('select').filter(function() { return this.value === 'yes'; }).each(function() {
        sum += +$(this).parent().find('input').val();
    });
    $ ('#total_threeprice').val( sum.toFixed(2));
   calculate(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to use dropdowns to do this. It would be more practical if you just have 3 checkboxes with the values and use a form (no javascript needed).

Comment: `#threeprice` doesn't exist.

Comment: JF I made a qiuck  jsfiddle. geekymartian not sure you understand what I am trying to do so I don't think you can make that type of comment.
Shomz sorry typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick to do that:

```
$('select').live('change',function() {

    if($(this).val() == 'yes')
    {
        var id = this.id;

        $('input.test1#'+id).val($('input.test#'+id).val())
    }
    else
    {

        $('input.test1#'+this.id).val("");
    }
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8DMU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).find('option[value*=yes]').is(':selected'))
    {
       var nr = $(this).attr('name').replace('switch','');

        $("[name*='total_"+nr+"price']").val($("input[name*='"+nr+"price']").val());
    }
})
```